# routing with params in vuejs using router-link

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to build a spa using vuejs in which I have a list of users now when I click a user it should route to a new page with user details of the particular user how to params the user id in router-link

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a Q/A site for specific programming questions. Asking for code or for recommendations of things is off-topic. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out more about this. Making an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have already tried is an appreciated concept.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can pass params in router link using

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 }}">User</router-link>
```

Here "name" key parameter defines the name of the route and "params" key defines the parameters you need to send with that route.

If you need to use Route Path instead of Route name, You can use.

```html
<router-link :to="{ path: 'home', params: { userId: 123 }}">Home</router-link>
```

[Reference](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to)

Comment: how do i pass this parameter in get my request in the routed page?

Comment: Why would you want that? Any particular reasons.

Comment: to fetch data with that id. I figured it out thanks for the help

Comment: for me <router-link :to="{ path: 'home', params: { userId: 123 }}">Home</router-link>

Does not work. Do you know what could be the reason for that?

Comment: @Romick Looks like `params: {...}` doesn't work with _path_ routes, only with named routes.

Comment: The second example is wrong. "path" and "params" don't work together.

Answer (score 25):

Looks like `params: {...}` doesn't work on non-named routes so to get that working I had to make my links like this:

```
<router-link :to="'/view-customer/' + customer.ID">
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case, your answer just prompted me to name my routes :)

Answer (score 17):

With ES6 template literals:

`` <router-link :to="`/books/${book.id}`"></router-link> ``

Answer (score 5):

solution for non-named routes:

```
<router-link :to="{ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' }}"
  >Register</router-link>
```

resulting in `/register?plan=private`

source: [Documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to)

Answer (score 4):

router/index.js:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import List from '../views/List.vue'
import Item from '../views/Item.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'List',
    component: List
  },
  {
    path: '/item/:id',
    name: 'Item',
    component: Item
  }
  }
]
```

List.vue:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Item', params: { id: data.item.id }}">{{ data.item.id }}</router-link>
```

Item.vue:

```
<template>
    id: {{ $route.params.id }}
</template>

<script>
    return this.$route.params.id
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this and it's works fine:

```
<router-link :to="'/home?id=' + customer.ID">
```

Also use the following code to retrieve it:

```
this.$route.query.id
```

Comment: this isn't fine, because its an ugly URL for the customers, who wants an ID attached to the end of their home URL?

Answer (score 0):

Routes declaration

```js
{path: '/insta-view/:name', name: 'instaFrontView', component: instaFrontViewComponent},
```

Bind parameter using the **path**

```js
<router-link :to="'insta-view/'+ loginUserName" class="nav-link"> View</router-link>
```

Bind parameter using the **name**

```js
<router-link :to="{ name: 'instaFrontView', params: { name: loginUserName }}" class="nav-link"> View</router-link>
```

```js
export default {
data() {
    return {
      loginUserName: 'test',
    }
  },
}
```

Retrieve parameter in code

```js
this.$route.params.name
```