# Uncaught error missing param when using named router-link

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

I am following a [YouTube course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLntPx3LFRY&list=PLpyspNLjzwBnpvPsDoQDv_EoI-GA9ptIu&index=3), and I encountered an error on the last part where I added a button for the EditClient route. I'm getting an `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing required param "id"`.

router/index.js:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Dashboard from '../views/dashboard/Dashboard.vue'
import MyAccount from '../views/dashboard/MyAccount.vue'
import SignUp from '../views/SignUp.vue'
import Login from '../views/Login.vue'
import Clients from '../views/dashboard/Clients.vue'
import Client from '../views/dashboard/Client.vue'
import AddClient from '../views/dashboard/AddClient.vue'
import EditClient from '../views/dashboard/EditClient.vue'
import EditTeam from '../views/dashboard/EditTeam.vue'
import Invoices from '../views/dashboard/Invoices.vue'
import Invoice from '../views/dashboard/Invoice.vue'
import AddInvoice from '../views/dashboard/AddInvoice.vue'

import store from '../store'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },

  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  },

  {
    path: '/sign-up',
    name: 'SignUp',
    component: SignUp
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  },
  
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: Dashboard,
    meta: {
      requireLogin: true
    }
  },
  
  {
    path: '/dashboard/invoices',
    name: 'Invoices',
    component: Invoices,
    meta: {
      requireLogin: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard/invoices/add',
    name: 'AddInvoice',
    component: AddInvoice,
    meta: {
      requireLogin: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard/invoices/:id',
    name: 'Invoice',
    component: Invoice,
    meta: {
      requireLogin: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard/clients',
    name: 'Clients',
    component: Clients,
    meta: {
      requireLogin: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard/clients/add',
    name: 'AddClient',
    component: AddClient,
    meta: {
      requireLogin: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard/clients/:id',
    name: 'Client',
    component: Client,
    meta: {
      requireLogin: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard/clients/:id/edit',
    name: 'EditClient',
    component: EditClient,
    meta: {
      requireLogin: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard/my-account',
    name: 'MyAccount',
    component: MyAccount,
    meta: {
      requireLogin: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard/my-account/edit-team',
    name: 'EditTeam',
    component: EditTeam,
    meta: {
      requireLogin: true
    }
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireLogin) && !store.state.isAuthenticated) {
    next('/login')
  }
  else {
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

My router link is as follows:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'EditClient', params: { id: client.id }}" class="button is-light mt-4">Edit</router-link>
```

I have tried, and it works:

```
<router-link :to="'/dashboard/clients/' + client.id + '/edit'" class="button is-light mt-4">Edit</router-link>
```

answer by Pylinux from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734357/routing-with-params-in-vuejs-using-router-link) question.

Although the solution is already acceptable, I would like to know why this is happening in my case.

Comment: It is possible to share the router.js code here?

Comment: I have attached it to the question [updated]